# RVM system wide install problems

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed RVM system wide on Fedora 14, and I pretty much followed the [guide](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/) to the letter. When I tried it out though:

```
$ type rvm | head -n1
rvm is /usr/local/bin/rvm
```

Most commands appear to work fine, but changing Rubies doesn't work properly. I have to keep logging off and back in for it to switch, and that doesn't seem to work every time.

Here's exactly what I did:

- `bash < <( curl -L http://bit.ly/rvm-install-system-wide )` as root
- add my own user to the rvm group
- add

  ```
  [[ -s "/usr/local/lib/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/lib/rvm"
  ```

  to the very end of `~/.bash_profile`.
- Log off and back in.

If I understood correctly, this is exactly what should be done. I made sure `.bashrc` doesn't contain a return statement.

I figure this has something to do with the environment variables that RVM sets up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you assuming something's wrong?

Comment: It could help to know what OS you're installing it on as the install-system-wide script seems to do a lot of OS-specific juggling. Also, if you have a look at the script you'll see that there are --trace and --debug arguments. You'll probably have to download the script first to supply those, though.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the problem. I just can't get ruby switching to work reliably. I'll have a look at those arguments.

Comment: Ping Wayne Seguin at his email address found by `rvm -v`. System-wide installs were originally a hack on RVM so they're not as well tested as a normal `~/.rvm` sandbox installation. He's incredibly responsive and very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer.

The problem was that I was not running bash as a login shell. This basically means it doesn't execute my ~/.bash_profile.

Embarrassing thing is, on the very, very last point on the troubleshooting guide is written:

> If you are using GNOME on Red Hat, CentOS or Fedora ensure that the Run command as login shell option is checked under the Title and Command tab in Profile Preferences. After changing this setting, you may need to exit your console session and start a new one before the changes take affect.

Looks like I didn't actually read the whole thing, but Wayne does need to put "Make sure you're running the shell as a login shell" on the guide itself, not just on the troubleshooting section.

Comment: "Wayne does need to put "Make sure you're running the shell as a login shell" on the guide itself, not just on the troubleshooting section". Actually it should read that plus "if your name is MatheusM". :-) Actually, it's cool you found the problem. Enjoy it. And, be sure to mark your answer as accepted since you found the problem.

Comment: Now that's what I'd call personalized customer service. :P

Comment: *Or* you could have added the rvm initialization to your .bashrc, too.  There's really no reason to run a login shell if you're already logged in.